# How do I generate a heap dump for my JBoss process without jhat or jstat?

Tags: java, jboss, heap-memory, heap-dump

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3 with the following Java, Linux versions …

```
[dave@mymachine ~]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
[dave@mymachine ~]$ uname -a
Linux mymachine.mydomain.org 4.1.99-99.88.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 5 23:44:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to figure out how much heap is being used (not the maximum amount, but what is currently being used).  Sadly, on our machine I don’t have access to jmap or jstat.  So I wanted to do a heap dump using “kill -3”.  So I first got the pid of my boss process

```
[dave@mymachine ~]$ ps -elf | grep jboss
1 S root      1251     1  0  80   0 - 28870 -      07:03 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /etc/rc3.d/S84jboss start
4 S root      1254  1251  0  80   0 - 34424 -      07:03 ?        00:00:00 runuser -s /bin/bash jboss -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jbos-as-standalone.pid /usr/java/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
4 S jboss     1255  1254  0  80   0 - 28271 -      07:03 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid /usr/java/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
0 S jboss     1256  1255  0  80   0 - 28272 -      07:03 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/java/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
0 S jboss     1289  1256  3  80   0 - 603908 -     07:03 ?        00:18:26 /usr/java/default/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/java/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/java/jboss/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/java/jboss/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/java/jboss -Djbos.server.base.dir=/usr/java/jboss/standalone -c standalone.xml
0 S 602      21746 20632  0  80   0 - 27615 pipe_w 16:46 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto jboss
```

and then I ran “kill -3” …

```
[dave@mymachine ~]$ sudo kill -3 1289 1256
```

but nothing prints out and no file is generated in the current directory.  How do I generate a heap dump with my current constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit old question, it is worth mentioning that you can also generate an Heap dump with any tool available in the JDK such as **jconsole** or external tools like **jvisualvm**.

Besides, you can also deploy a component such as a Servlet in Jboss to trigger the Heap dump programmatically:

```
HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(
                HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);

// Invoke the dumpHeap method to generate the heap dump
mxBean.dumpHeap(filePath, true);
```

Source : [How to generate an Heap Dump in Java](https://www.mastertheboss.com/java/how-to-capture-an-heap-dump-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the main reason that you do not have access to the excellent serviceability tools like `jmap`, `jstack` etc. is that they are *not* part of the `openjdk-6-jre`, or `openjdk-7-jre` Linux packages (I am assuming debian distro here). I do not understand why that should be the case. In my opinion, these tools should be a part of the `JRE` and not the `JDK`. Here's the proof:

```
$> apt-file list openjdk-6-jdk | grep jmap
openjdk-6-jdk: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jmap
openjdk-6-jdk: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.eucJP/man1/jmap.1.gz
openjdk-6-jdk: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jmap.1.gz
$> apt-file list openjdk-6-jre | grep jmap
<nothing>
```

Anyway, to get these tools, you should consider using the JDK and install them using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`. This should get you not only the latest JDK 6 build (which, btw, *very very* old). Then, you should get the access to the tools that give us the heap dump for later analysis.

Heap dump is very different from the thread dump which shows you what the JVM threads are doing. One way to get the *thread dump* is by sending the `QUIT` signal to JVM process (using, like you said: `kill -3`). This will show the thread dump wherever the JVM's stdout is redirected. An (almost) equivalent tool is `jstack`, which is, again, a part of the *JDK* package, and not the *JRE* package.

But thread dump is not what you need. You need heap dump. So, you need `jmap`.

Short of this, you can estimate the actual memory being used by the JVM using the indispensable Linux `top` command. Make sure that you analyze the output correctly to get an estimate of how much heap is being used by the JVM.

If you are experiencing an `OutOfMemoryError` in your JVM, then you should consider starting it with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` so that when `OOME` is thrown, at least you can get a heap dump. But this way, you can get the heap dump only after you run out of heap space!

Comment: As I said in my question, I do not have access to jmap, nor the power to install these tools.  How would I figure out an approxiamte heap size using "top"?   My Linux distro info is included in my question (at the top).

Comment: It was not clear _why_ you don't have access to `jmap`, so I thought I'd clarify. Using `top/freemem/ps/smem` to estimate memory used by processes is described at multiple places: cf. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802481/how-to-see-top-processes-by-actual-memory-usage). There's nothing specific to the JVM here. Linux treats JVM process like any other.

Comment: So I'm clear, the link you posted describing top does not make any mention of Java heap.  The "RES" and "SHR" memroy stats reported by top do not in any way to pertain to the actual amount of Java heap memory being used, but correct me if I am misstating things.

Comment: Right. You can make an estimate using those tools. `top` et.al. report the memory (RSS/SHR) used by the operating system process. You can also take some hints from the `-Xmx` setting that you used to start the JVM, to connect the dots. `-Xmx` specifies the maximum addressable (virtual) heap memory that you ask the JVM to ask the OS for, when it starts. There's a good deal of literature about `-Xmx` that you should consult.

Comment: For some reason I am difficulty communicating what I want to do.  I do not care about the maximum heap allocated (as specified by "-Xmx"), I want to know how much heap is currently used.  "RES" as reported by top, is the allowed memory to a java process, again not what I want.  It's cool if you don't know the answer, neither do I!

Comment: If you want to know "how much heap is currently used" under the given circumstances on your Linux box, then yes, I don't know. But I still believe that my answer to your original question is valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105851/discussion-between-kedar-mhaswade-and-dave).

Comment: To be clear, top shows the process size, not the size of Java heap nor it's live occupancy. For that you need to use tools that understand the internal data structures of the JVM. Those tools would include jmap and a generic mbean viewer as is found in JConsole (also only found in the JDK, not JRE).

Answer (score -1):

set -XX:HeapDumpPath=mpath/heapdump to a writable directory or file on java's command line for starting up JBOSS. 
This path/file  needs to be writable for the user JBOSS is running under and then try the kill -3 option again.

[http://five.agency/java-heap-dump/](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java)

You could also problematically do a heap dump using the HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean from your application also.

see [class to dump heap](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java)