# Using LINUX top command to compute used memory percentage

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing the top command output to a text file.
I am trying to write a simple bash script to calculate the percentage of used memory and send an 
email if the memory used percentage exceeds, say 90%.

Here is the bash script I have thus far.

```
#!/bin/bash
top -n 1 -b | grep "Mem" > /home/modadm/top-output.txt
MAXMEM=/home/modadm/top-output.txt | grep "Mem" | cut -c 7-14 
USEDMEM=/home/modadm/top-output.txt | grep "Mem" | cut -c 25-31
$USEDPCT='echo $USEDMEM / $MAXMEM * 100 | bc'
$USEDPCT | mail -s "Test Email from MOD Server" test@test.com
```

When I save and execute the script, I get the error "No such file or directory":

```
-bash-3.2$ ./memcheck.sh
./memcheck.sh: line 4: =echo $USEDMEM / $MAXMEM * 100 | bc: No such file or directory
Null message body; hope that's ok
-bash-3.2$
```

Can someone assist? I am a newbie to bash scripting and this is my first script.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

First, this doesn't do what you want it to do.

```
USEDMEM=/home/modadm/top-output.txt | grep "Mem" | cut -c 25-31
```

You can't pipe a filename into a command. You actually want to pipe the contents of the file into the command. You can do that with 'cat'. However, grep is actually designed to search within a file so you can do

```
USEDMEM=$(grep "Mem" /home/modadm/top-output.txt | cut -c 25-31)
```

Note that $(cmd) is how you execute a command in a subshell. i.e., you can run some commands to compute the value of a variable in your script. You can also use `cmd` (backticks; usually on the tilde key) but that syntax is less clear.

Again, you probably want to calculate this result in a subshell. Also, don't use $ when assigning to variables.

```
$USEDPCT='echo $USEDMEM / $MAXMEM * 100 | bc'
```

This can be rewritten as

```
USEDPCT=$(echo "scale=3; $USEDMEM / $MAXMEM * 100" | bc)
```

Finally, you want to pipe the contents of the variable into the mail program. The pipe is expecting a program to be on the left hand side. You do this by echo'ing the value of the variable into the pipe.

```
echo "$USEDPCT" | mail -s "Test Email from MOD Server" test@test.com
```

To put everything back together:

```
#!/bin/bash
top -n 1 -b | grep "Mem" > /home/modadm/top-output.txt
MAXMEM=$(grep "Mem" /home/modadm/top-output.txt | cut -c 7-14)
USEDMEM=$(grep "Mem" /home/modadm/top-output.txt | cut -c 25-31)
USEDPCT=$(echo "$USEDMEM / $MAXMEM * 100" | bc -l)
echo "$USEDPCT" | mail -s "Test Email from MOD Server" test@test.com
```

Comment: Awesome! Chris, thank you very much for providing me a line by line explanation of where I was going wrong!!. Thanks again.

Comment: I modified the last line to round off the percentage to: USEDPCTSRND=$(echo "scale=4; $USEDPCT" | bc) 
USEDPCTS="Current used MOD server memory is: "$USEDPCTSRND" %"
echo "$USEDPCTS" | bc | mail -s "MOD Server:Memory Usage" test@test.com But the rounding does not work! Could you pls help? Thanks.

Comment: @user765081 I updated the answer to round off the percentage calculation. Good luck

Comment: One last thing under this question, I am trying to add a carriage return between the text and the percentage value: I modified the last 2 lines as: USEDPCTS="Current used DOM server memory is " $'2 \n' $USEDPCT " %", and the last line as echo -e "$USEDPCTS" | mail -s "DOM Server Memory Usage" test@test.com   But I get an error. Pls dont mind. Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I will not repeat the content of the other answers; instead I will question the wisdom of parsing the output of `top`, when all you need is information on the system memory usage.

The output of `top` is intended for humans and also contains a lot of per-process information that is both unneeded and expensive to produce. The output of [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/free) is far more suitable for this particular use.

Secondly, judging by the calculations in your script, you do not seem to understand the way system memory usage is measured on Linux and other Unix-like systems. Contrary to the *other* OS, the used memory size contains the memory used for disk caches and other buffers. On any system that has been up for some time the free memory tends towards zero - unused memory is wasted memory.

A first step towards finding out the amount of memory used by processes would be to subtract the amount of memory used for buffers from the used memory size. But even that would not be enough on a modern system - even `free` and `top` get it wrong to a degree, as mentioned in [this older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4417121/507519).

Comment: thkala: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Will try the free command instead of top. The code corrections posted by others gave me an opportunity to take my first shot at bash shell scripting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out problems with your code, but there are much easier options for this, namely not parsing `top` output at all. Use `/proc/meminfo`, and `awk` - you won't need a temporary file.

```
$ awk '/MemTotal:/{total=$2} \
       /MemFree:/{free=$2} \
       END{ \
        print "Free mem percent: "(free*100/total); \
        print "Used mem percent: "((total-free)*100/total) \
       }' /proc/meminfo 

Free mem percent: 87.7348
Used mem percent: 12.2652
```

Pipe that to `mail` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your syntax errors. Pl. note the use of command substitution, 
like you have written

```
MAXMEM=/home/modadm/top-output.txt | grep "Mem" | cut -c 7-14.
```

This is wrong, you need to write

```
 grep "Mem" /home/modadm/top-output.txt | cut -c 7-14
```

and then enclose it within backquotes(the key at the lefthand side over tab key) to assign final value to a variable. 
Also you have written,

```
$USEDPCT='echo $USEDMEM / $MAXMEM * 100 | bc'
```

The dollar sign is used wrongly. $ should be used when you are using  the value of
a variable.The quotes should be ` (back quote) and not '(single quote). Backquote means  the command will be substituted with the output of the command.
Also for floating point bc needs a scale to be set.

Pl. see the modified code. Hope this helps. Pl. note I have not checked the functionality of the mail command that if it is sending mail or not.

```
top -n 1 -b | grep "Mem" > /home/modadm/top-output.txt
MAXMEM=`grep "Mem" /home/modadm/top-output.txt | cut -c 7-14`
USEDMEM=`grep "Mem" /home/modadm/top-output.txt | cut -c 25-31`
USEDPCT=`echo   "scale=2; $USEDMEM / $MAXMEM * 100" | bc `
echo $USEDPCT | mail -s "Test Email from MOD Server" test@test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script.

```
#! /bin/bash

memusage=`top -n 1 -b | grep "Mem"`
MAXMEM=`echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f2 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}'`
USEDMEM=`echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f4 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}'`

USEDMEM1=`expr $USEDMEM \* 100`
PERCENTAGE=`expr $USEDMEM1 / $MAXMEM`%

echo $PERCENTAGE | mail -s "Test Email" test@test.com
```