# How to find user memory usage in linux

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

How i can see memory usage by user in linux centos 6

```
For example:
    USER    USAGE
    root    40370
    admin   247372
    user2   30570
    user3   967373
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Per-user memory usage in percent using standard tools:

```
for _user in $(ps haux | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)
do
    ps haux | awk -v user=${_user} '$1 ~ user { sum += $4} END { print user, sum; }'            
done
```

or for more precision:

```
TOTAL=$(free | awk '/Mem:/ { print $2 }')
for _user in $(ps haux | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)
do
    ps hux -U ${_user} | awk -v user=${_user} -v total=$TOTAL '{ sum += $6 } END { printf "%s %.2f\n", user, sum / total * 100; }'
done
```

The first version just sums up the memory percentage for each process as reported by `ps`. The second version sums up the memory in bytes instead and calculates the total percentage afterwards, thus leading to a higher precision.

Comment: It works but not fine. My memory usage is full (99%) but sum of the your command result show less than 15%

Comment: Where did you get your *99%* from?

Comment: I'm using `free` command and it show me `total:2047372` `used:2014592`

Comment: You are interpreting the output of `free` wrong, please read the answers to [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784974/want-to-know-whether-enough-memory-is-free-on-a-linux-machine-to-deploy-a-new-ap) [questions](http://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free) (keywords: buffers/cache). The output of my answer is correct.

Comment: Good logic, but my `ps` on SUSE 13.2 did weird things with long  usernames, eg "garfieldthecat" would show up as "garfiel+", and then the summing wouldn't work.  Also beware that `$USER` is a built-in variable for the current user in most shells.

Comment: What about memory shared between processes? Cannot this approach sum some memory bytes twice?

Answer (score 47):

This one-liner worked for me on at least four different Linux systems with different distros and versions. It also worked on FreeBSD 10.

```
ps hax -o rss,user | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;}END{for(i in a)print i" "int(a[i]/1024+0.5);}' | sort -rnk2
```

About the implementation, there are no shell loop constructs here; this uses an associative array in `awk` to do the grouping & summation.

Here's sample output from one of my servers that is running a decent sized MySQL, Tomcat, and Apache.  Figures are in MB.

```
mysql 1566
joshua 1186                                                                                  
tomcat 353                                                                                   
root 28                                                                                      
wwwrun 12                                                                                    
vbox 1                                                                                       
messagebus 1                                                                                 
avahi 1                                                                                      
statd 0                                                                                      
nagios 0
```

Caveat: like most similar solutions, this is only considering the resident set (RSS), so it doesn't count any shared memory segments.

**EDIT**: A more human-readable version.

```
echo "USER                 RSS      PROCS" ; echo "-------------------- -------- -----" ; ps hax -o rss,user | awk '{rss[$2]+=$1;procs[$2]+=1;}END{for(user in rss) printf "%-20s %8.0f %5.0f\n", user, rss[user]/1024, procs[user];}' | sort -rnk2
```

And the output:

```
USER                 RSS      PROCS
-------------------- -------- -----
mysql                    1521     1
joshua                   1120    28
tomcat                    379     1
root                       19   107
wwwrun                     10    10
vbox                        1     3
statd                       1     1
nagios                      1     1
messagebus                  1     1
avahi                       1     1
```

Comment: Why "+0.5" though?

Comment: @Daniel, awk's `int( )` function is a floor function.  Adding the 0.5 makes it do proper rounding.  So if a process is using 3.9 MB, int(3.9) would display as only 3.   But int(3.9+0.5) = 4.

Comment: Is it possible to select only processes running with a specific COMMAND (say R)?

Comment: @utobi Try `ps --no-headers -o rss,user $(pidof R) | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;}END{for(i in a)print i" "int(a[i]/1024+0.5);}' | sort -rnk2`

Comment: it doesn't work. It counts other things that are not R processes. e.g. a user is currently running 9 R processes but the command you suggest geves 364. I tried with `ps hax -o rss,user,command | grep exec/R | awk '{rss[$2]+=$1;procs[$2]+=1;}END{for(user in rss) printf "%-20s %8.0f %5.0f\n", user, rss[user]/1024, procs[user];}' | sort -rnk2` but still is not fully reliable...

Comment: @utobi,  Analyzing... what does `pidof R` show.  Does this correctly identify just your R processes?

Comment: It lists 40 PID which actually correspond to R processes. The number seems correct. I've lunched again your suggestion in the previous comment and it seems to give the RAM used by each user (perhaps due to the R processes) but not counts of R processes.

Comment: @utobi So are you looking for the number of R processes and total RAM used by them, grouped per user?  Like for some server where multiple developers run R under their own accounts?

Comment: @utobi, try `echo "USER                 RSS      PROCS" ; echo "-------------------- -------- -----" ; pidof R | while read PID ; do ps --no-header -o rss,user -p $PID ; done | awk '{rss[$2]+=$1;procs[$2]+=1;}END{for(user in rss) printf "%-20s %8.0f %5.0f\n", user, rss[user]/1024, procs[user];}' | sort -rnk2`

Answer (score 17):

If your system supports, try to install and use [smem](http://www.selenic.com/smem/):

```
smem -u

User     Count     Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
gdm          1        0      308      323      820 
nobody       1        0      912      932     2240 
root        76        0   969016  1010829  1347768
```

or

```
smem -u -t -k

User     Count     Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
gdm          1        0   308.0K   323.0K   820.0K 
nobody       1        0   892.0K   912.0K     2.2M 
root        76        0   937.6M   978.5M     1.3G 
ameskaas    46        0     1.2G     1.2G     1.5G
```

---

```
           124        0     2.1G     2.2G     2.8G
```

In Ubuntu, smem can be installed by typing

```
sudo apt install smem
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return the total ram usage by users in GBs, reverse sorted

```
sudo ps --no-headers -eo user,rss | awk '{arr[$1]+=$2}; END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]/1024/1024}}' | sort -nk2 -r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Python script to find per-user memory usage using only sys and os module.

```
import sys
import os

# Get list of all users present in the system
allUsers = os.popen('cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd').read().split('\n')[:-1]

for users in allUsers:
    # Check if the home directory exists for the user
    if os.path.exists('/home/' + str(users)):
        # Print the current usage of the user
        print(os.system('du -sh /home/' + str(users)))
```

Comment: I appears you confused memory usage with storage usage. Memory usage refers to RAM while the solution you provided accounts for the space used on disk.